# JPA. Filter entities where a field Set<> contains certain value

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity where one of fields is `<Set> groups.`

```
@Entity
public class TimetableItem {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
    
        /*different fields */
    
   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(name = "timetable_items_groups",
              joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "timetable_item_id"),
              inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"))
  private Set<Group> groups;
```

I need to get all timetable items where the Set contains a certain group (Set can have a lot of different groups too. And if "my group" is one of them -  it's that I need).

```
public List<TimetableItem> findItemsWithGroup(Group group) {
   CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
   CriteriaQuery<TimetableItem> query = cb.createQuery(TimetableItem.class);
   Root<TimetableItem> root = query.from(TimetableItem.class);

   //something like that but it doesn’t work
   Predicate predicateForGroup = cb.isTrue(root.get(TimetableItem_.GROUPS).in(group));

   query.where(predicateForGroup);
List<TimetableItem> timetableItems = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

If I run the code without any conditions, I can see in debugger that my `List<TimetableItem> timetableItems`  has all items from database and each of them has `Set<Group>` with groups inside it.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy590.jpg)

Of course, I can find the items which I need “manually” (with .stream() for example) but I’m sure there is some way to get it using predicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the CriteriaBuilder.isMember-Method:

```
Predicate predicateForGroup = cb.isMember(group, root.get(TimetableItem_.GROUPS));
```

Comment: Wow!!! It really works!!!!! Thank you very much Frank !!!!!!! :)